# GraalVM native-image: how to disable auto-detected internal GsonFeature?

Tags: graalvm, graalvm-native-image

During my GraalVM native image build GsonFeature is auto detected and enabled:

```
1 user-specific feature(s)
 - com.oracle.svm.thirdparty.gson.GsonFeature
```

This Feature registeres reflective access to `sun.misc.Unsafe` that I don't use. I want to disable it but don't know how.

The `--features` compiler flag allows to enable specific Features but it seems there is no way do disable auto-detected ones.

Comment: have you tried to [manual configuration](https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/native-image/Reflection/#manual-configuration)?